# 'X questions with new activity' shows new question, Clicking on Newest on top still shows older questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, live-refresh

Does anyone else see this at their end? I could almost swear this isn't how this used to work earlier (so it probably can't be by choice)?[image]

Comment: Having run into this myself on another site: Caching. The question list is cached, and when you refresh you get the old cache (unless you catch it literally right after the cache updates.) and therefore don't have the new question. (I don't remember if it's client side or server side, however.)

Comment: This is caused by your horrible terrible custom cursor.

Comment: @Will That circle thing is only shown in the video, to emphasise where the clicks were made.

Comment: You think I'm talking about that???  I'm talking about that little horribly rendered mickey mouse hand!  It looks like a monkey paw and my dead son is going to start pounding on my front door!  LET THE DEAD SLEEP!

Comment: @Will - That's the default Mac OS X cursor. I'm pointing a monkey paw in your general direction right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question list is cached, but most recent the live-refresh updates are not part of that cached copy yet. They will be in a few minutes (after which more live updates will quickly make the cache out of date again).

This behaviour has been unchanged since they introduced the live-refresh feature.

I know this because I've been irritated by it a few times as I accidentally switched views just as a new post came in and I *know* I won't be able to load it for the next few minutes.