# When question with new activity is clicked bug?

Tags: bug

I am not sure this is a bug or just browser functionality. When there is the option to click on question with new activity.

[image]

If you click it.

[image]

If you click on the newest question.

[image]

Then if you click back on the browser, it takes you back to the original page without the new questions on it. Why is this and Is it a problem?

[image]

Comment: Caching. The answer is caching.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298964/

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @Kendra Yeah it's kind of related, I did not see that.

Comment: Honestly, Philip, I wouldn't have found it if I hadn't commented on it. (And took the time to dig through my comments to find it.) The answer to that question actually answers yours- It's the same cause, you just achieved it in a slightly different manner.