# Automatic New Question Banner/Back button bug + Possible Solution?

Tags: bug

**How to reproduce the bug:**

1. Search up any tag in the search bar.
2. Wait for a new question to be submitted and then when the New Question Banner pops up, click on it.
3. The questions are automatically rendered most likely through AJAX. Click on one of the newly rendered questions.
4. Then click the browser back button.
5. The new questions are not there any more. You have to manually refresh the page to retrieve them

I've so far tested this bug only in Chrome, but I think the same problem will arise in other browsers too. I think the problem is caused by loading the new questions through Javascript. When you click on the New Question Banner, there is no page refresh; thus the browser does not recognize that the page has been updated. When you click the back button while on the Question Page, the page caching system kicks in and reverts back to how the server generated the page completely ignoring the new content loaded through Javascript.

I realize that there's another question very similar to this one: ['X questions with new activity' shows new question, Clicking on Newest on top still shows older questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298964/x-questions-with-new-activity-shows-new-question-clicking-on-newest-on-top-st) However...

*This bug is very irritating since I don't see the point in having a notification for new questions if it just loads through Javascript. It might as well be a live loading system where new questions are added to the list without warning. The notification should only be used if there's a possible disruption in the user's experience like a page refresh.*

**Possible Solution ?**
When the New Question Banner pops up, can we have it so that it just refreshes the page through Javascript, thus we can bypass the page cache.